# Swift - filter with n complexity

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, code-complexity

So i want to filter an array with n complexity.
The objective is to recognise the duplicate card(by id) and keep the card with status "a" and add him to the array(filter out the duplicate with status that different from "a")
The code i have is as follow:

```
struct Card {
 var id:String
 var status:String

init(id:String, status:String) {
    self.id = id
    self.status = status
 }
}

let card1 = Card(id: "123", status: "a")
let card3 = Card(id: "43", status: "a")
let card4 = Card(id: "45", status: "a")
let card2 = Card(id: "123", status: "b")
let card5 = Card(id: "1234", status: "c")


let arrr = [card1,card3,card4,card2,card5]




func getCreditCardsOnly(creditCardsData:[Card]) -> [Card] {
var filter = [Card]()

for card in creditCardsData {
    if !filter.contains(where: {$0.id == card.id && $0.status != "b"}) {
        filter.append(card)
    }
}

 return filter
}
```

the output is:

> Card(id: "123", status: "a"), Card(id: "43", status: "a"), Card(id: "45", status: "a"), Card(id: "1234", status: "c")]

As wanted, yet the complexity is n^2.
Is there a way to lower the complexity?

Comment: So if you'd also have `Card(id: "1", status: "b")` in the array, that should stay in the array, right? You only want to filter out duplicates, whose `status` is `b`? What if there are 2 cards with the same id and statuses of `a` and `c`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor , yes you right.
if there are 2 cards with the same id and statuses of a and c i want them out also.
not duplicate with status a

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dictionary's` **`init(grouping:by:)`** and `filter(_:)` to get the expected `result`, i.e.

```
let result = Dictionary(grouping: arrr, by: { $0.status }).values.filter({ $0.first?.status != "b"})
print(result)
```

The above code has complexity *O(n)*.

Comment: @hi
my answer is [[__lldb_expr_19.Card(id: "45", status: "a")], [__lldb_expr_19.Card(id: "43", status: "a")]]

as said i need also Card(id: "123", status: "a")

Comment: The grouping is incorrect ...

if i add anther card as so :

let card1 = Card(id: "123", status: "a")
let card3 = Card(id: "43", status: "a")
let card4 = Card(id: "45", status: "a")
let card2 = Card(id: "123", status: "b")
let card5 = Card(id: "1234", status: "c")

i wont see hime in the arr

Comment: Kindy update the question with proper explanation of the conditions on which you want to filter. It is unclear.

Comment: Yes. Write the code in it and return result from it.

Comment: No, still dont have a different answer